# Do embedded Youtube videos increase the site's bandwidth?

Tags: html, xhtml, download, bandwidth

By having each classified ad with embedded Youtube video, will this increase the bandwidth of the site? If so, would iFrame help in anyway? Thank.

Answer (score 7):

No, it will not. You're serving content from Youtube, not your server. The only increase in bandwidth you will see will be with the extra HTML you're serving for the embed.

Answer (score 2):

No change in bandwidth as the embedded videos are handled by the browser which get the data directly from the youtube server..

So the only interaction is between the client and youtube .. nothing goes through your server..

Comment: Oh no, wonder why my webhosting staff are noobie. Misled me for a year. Thank you for your answer!